# Como usar o JUnit com Demoiselle 2.4.2?

Tags: java, demoiselle, junit

Olá

Tenho um projeto com o seguinte perfil:

- Eclipse Luna
- Java 6
- JSF 2.2/Primefaces 5.3
- JBoss 7
- Demoiselle 2.4.2.

A aplicação já funciona, o problema está na execução de casos de teste do **JUnit 4.12**. O caso de teste mostrado a seguir corresponde à invocação de um método de um *managed bean* anotado com `@ViewController`, ou seja, é o teste de um *backing bean* de uma página **XHTML**:

```
@RunWith(DemoiselleRunner.class)
public class CaixaAberturaTests {

    @Inject
    CaixaOperacaoEditMB caixaOperacao;

    @Test
    public void shouldConfirmarAberturaParaUsuarioLogado() {
        // Arrange
        caixaOperacao.setSaldoInicial(new BigDecimal(100.00));

        // Act
        String destino = caixaOperacao.confirmarAbertura();

        // Assert
        assertNotNull(destino);
    }
}
```

Ao executar, a exceção é lançada na linha da sessão **Arrange**, que nada mais é do que a atribuição de uma valor a uma propriedade. O código de tal método segue abaixo:

```
public void setSaldoInicial(BigDecimal value) {
  saldoInicial = value; 
}
```

No entanto, o método nunca chega a ser executado, é interceptado antes e neste processo é que a exceção é lançada, conforme *stack* a seguir:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.FacesViewContextImpl.getSession(FacesViewContextImpl.java:143)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.FacesViewContextImpl.getStore(FacesViewContextImpl.java:88)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.AbstractCustomContext.get(AbstractCustomContext.java:92)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.context.AbstractCustomContext.get(AbstractCustomContext.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at br.ufpr.restaurante.view.CaixaOperacaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.setSaldoInicial(CaixaOperacaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at br.ufpr.restaurante.view.tests.CaixaAberturaTests.shouldConfirmarAberturaParaUsuarioLogado(CaixaAberturaTests.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.runChild(DemoiselleRunner.java:60)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.runChild(DemoiselleRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner.run(DemoiselleRunner.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Gostaria de alguma dica para solucionar o caso.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex o problema parece na injeção do ManagedBean, provavelmente  o demoiselle não está conseguindo fazer a Injeção por ser uma classe gerenciada pelo JSF. Geralmente as regras do negocio ficam nas classes com a anotação @BussinessController. Ainda não havia tentado injetar um ManagedBean. Você não possui uma classe CaixaOperacaoBC onde confirmarAbertura() está sendo de fato realizado?
Caso tenha, mude a classe de teste e altere seu metodo para receber o saldo (ou o objeto que o contem) e injete essa classe no seu teste. 
O ManagedBean basicamente irá obter os dados da tela e direcionar para a respectiva classe de negocio para realizar as regras. Nesse caso você não precisaria dele para seus testes.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Após vários testes e leituras, percebi que o problema é que para se usar o JUnit com `ViewControllers` é necessário usar _mocks_ para prover objetos de suporte da infra do JSF, como por exemplo `FacesContext`. Este agora tem sido o meu problema. Meu objetivo em incluir os `ViewControllers` é ter a maior taxa de cobertura de código nos testes unitários, pois é código da aplicação que também precisa estar assegurado. Como aplico o TDD, é natural que **todo** o código escrito tenha um caso de teste para ele.